# Prometheus : How to check if there is atleast one time series for a given metric and label combination?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I have metric, `LATENCY` and label, `status`.
I want to fire an alert when `LATENCY` has `status=CRITICAL`

```
LATENCY{status="CRITICAL"}
```

`LATENCY` status will be critical only if latency is beyond a threshold.
How to check if there is at least one time series with `LATENCY{status="CRITICAL"}` ?

I used `expr: absent(LATENCY{status="CRITICAL"}) == 0`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `count(LATENCY{status="CRITICAL"}) >0`?

Comment: @anemyte Thanks a lot, it works! Just curious can I just give expr: LATENCY{status="CRITICAL"} ? as alert will be considered active if there are one or more vector elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you could try the following expression:

```
count(LATENCY{status="CRITICAL"}) > 0
```

If it doesn't work as expected, then try the following one:

```
count(LATENCY{status="CRITICAL"} or vector(0)) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Just curious can I just give expr: LATENCY{status="CRITICAL"} ? as alert will be considered active if there are one or more vector elements

Comment: The expression must return true or false.

Comment: As per docs "Whenever the alert expression results in one or more vector elements at a given point in time, the alert counts as active for these elements' label sets." Am I missing something ? https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/

Comment: Uhm... I think you're right, I don't know why "LATENCY(status="CRITICAL"}" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

LATENCY{status="CRITICAL"} > bool 0